# Agregación en Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Pregunta original: [Aggregation in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53781634/aggregation-in-pandas). Me pareció muy útil, decidí traducirlo. Siéntete libre de corregir mi gramática.

---

1. ¿Qué es la agregación?
2. ¿Cómo realizar la agregación con Pandas?

[Para ser expandido.]

Comment: Muy buena pregunta respuesta!

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

---

### Pregunta 1

## ¿Qué es la agregación?

1. Tomando una serie de datos, subdividir los datos en grupos (*split*)
2. Aplicando alguna función a los grupos (*apply*)
3. Devolviendo la salida de forma estructurada (*combine*)

Los ejemplos están en la pregunta 2.

[Documentación.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html)

---

### Pregunta 2

## ¿Cómo realizar la agregación con Pandas?

Creemos un [`dataframe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) de ejemplo.

```
np.random.seed(123)

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo'],
                   'B' : ['one', 'two', 'three','two', 'two', 'one'],
                   'C' : np.random.randint(5, size=6),
                   'D' : np.random.randint(5, size=6),
                   'E' : np.random.randint(5, size=6)})
```

`print(df)` nos da:

```
     A      B  C  D  E
0  foo    one  2  3  0
1  foo    two  4  1  0
2  bar  three  2  1  1
3  foo    two  1  0  3
4  bar    two  3  1  4
5  foo    one  2  1  0
```

---

- **Agregación optimizada para Cython**

([sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html), [mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html), [std](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.std.html), [sem](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sem.html))

I. *groupby* una columna (`A`), calcular resultados para todas las columnas.

```
df1 = df.groupby(['A'], as_index=False).sum()
print (df1)
```

Resultado:

```
     A  C  D  E
0  bar  5  2  5
1  foo  9  5  3
```

---

II. *groupby* una columna (`A`), calcular los resultados de una sola columna (`C`):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['A'], as_index=False)['C'].sum()
print (df1)
```

Resultando:

```
     A  C
0  bar  5
1  foo  9
```

---

III. *groupby* varias columnas, calcular los resultados de una sola columna (`C`):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['A','B'], as_index=False)['C'].sum()
print (df1)
```

Resultando:

```
     A      B  C
0  bar  three  2
1  bar    two  3
2  foo    one  4
3  foo    two  5
```

---

- **Mismos resultados [usando DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):**

Mismos casos que arriba:

```
#I.:
df1 = df.groupby(['A'], as_index=False).agg(sum)

#II.:
df1 = df.groupby(['A'], as_index=False)['C'].agg(sum)

#III.:
df1 = df.groupby(['A','B'], as_index=False)['C'].agg(sum)
```